# Does the file need to be closed?

Tags: go, file-upload, go-gin

Using golang gin, I read file data using:

```
file, fileHeader, err:=ctx.Request.FormFile("blabla...")
```

Do I need to write this?

```
defer file.Close()
```

I jump to the source code, it says:

```
// Open opens and returns the FileHeader's associated File.
func (fh *FileHeader) Open() (File, error) {
        if b := fh.content; b != nil {
                r := io.NewSectionReader(bytes.NewReader(b), 0, int64(len(b)))
                fmt.Printf("TODDLINE:152\n")
                fmt.Printf("TODDLINE:154:fmpfile:%#v\n", fh.tmpfile)
                fmt.Printf("TODDLINE:154:Filename:%#v\n", fh.Filename)
                return sectionReadCloser{r}, nil
        }
        fmt.Printf("TODDLINE:155\n")
        return os.Open(fh.tmpfile)
}
```

If it uses os.Open, I guess I must close the file, but if it retuns the sectionReadCloser{r}, the Close function shows like this:

```
func (rc sectionReadCloser) Close() error {
        return nil
}
```

The close function of seciontReadCloser doesn't do anything.
And I find that it does return the sectionReadCloser{r}.
I guess I should close the file, but I still want to know when it will return the os.Open. I will keep going to read the source code and try to understand it. It would be nice if someone gives me some advice.

Answer (score 6):

If the `file` returned implements `io.Closer` (i.e., if it has a `Close` method), assume you are responsible for closing it unless the documentation explicitly states otherwise.